# perform two different fetch on the same query result

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have this query:

```
$all = $dbh->query("SELECT DISTINCT movimenti.nome, SUM(movimenti_carta.importo)
FROM movimenti_carta JOIN movimenti ON movimenti_carta.movimento=movimenti.id
WHERE month(data)='$mese' AND year(data)='$anno' GROUP BY movimenti.nome");
```

It retrieves two columns from my db. What I want to do is to put each column in a separate array. 
If I do:

```
$labels=$all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
```

I get the values for the first column with the format I am looking for. 
I tried to do:

```
$values=$all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,1);
```

after the first fetch but `$all` is unset by the first fetch and the result is that `$values` is an empty array (I was pretty sure of this but did give it a try).
I can build the arrays in php after I fetch an array with both columns but I was wondering how to get my goal using PDO api.

Comment: maybe use a second variable $second = $all; or $second = clone($all) ?

Comment: Maybe you can use `while` + `fetch` and put all elements in proper arrays?

Comment: @fky this doesn't work

Comment: @u_mulder do you mean one fetch and create then two arrays? Yes, I can do it but I was looking to create from the beginning two arrays. Maybe it is not doable and I have to manipulate the array in php

Comment: I suppose it's not doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it will never work this way, as fetchAll() returns data only once.

The only idea I could think of is [PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_KEY_PAIR) constant:

```
$data = $all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$labels = array_keys($data);
$values = array_values($data);
```

Comment: that's a very good idea. Thanks also for the link. I googled for PDO fetch modes but didn't notice this one

Answer (score 3):

It feels like you are overcomplicating this. It's easily done in PHP, and if you just use `PDOStatement::fetch`, you don't need to worry about array manipulation; it will also be more friendly to your memory usage if you have a lot of data.

```
$labels = [];
$values = [];

while ($row = $all->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $labels[] = $row[0];
    $values[] = $row[1];
}
```

Comment: thank you! I agree with you that this is easily done this way (actually this is the code I have set up). But was digging a bit deeper into PDO fetch modes and did try to have an alternative to this code in place

Comment: @LelioFaieta Honestly, it's probably the best way, even though it's not very exotic, because it's almost certainly the way with the lowest memory usage. The accepted answer uses twice as much.

Comment: yes. I know about the memory. The accepted answer is the one that answer the question but I agree that your is the way to follow (also because I have to manage big amount of rows)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$all = $dbh->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT movimenti.nome, SUM(movimenti_carta.importo) AS importo
    FROM movimenti_carta 
    JOIN movimenti ON movimenti_carta.movimento=movimenti.id
    WHERE month(data)='$mese' 
    AND year(data)='$anno' 
    GROUP BY movimenti.nome
");
// set of results indexed by column name
$results = $all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// set of values from the column 'nome'
$nomes = array_column($results, 'nome');
// set of values from the column 'importo'
$importos = array_column($results, 'importo');
```